# Spring Security: user with role is not able to access to endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've created this straightforward controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('VIEWER')")
    public List<String> list() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

As you can see, it's protected by `@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('VIEWER')")`.

According to logs:

```
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@99305100: Principal: username; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: VIEWER
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@4799314a, returned: -1
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@41e7ad2c, returned: 0
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@79a89d7d, returned: 0
Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

As you can see, user is authenticated and has role `VIEWER`. However, it's NOT able to reach `_/orders/list` endpoint since `"access is denied"`.

Previous log snippet:

> Principal: username; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: VIEWER

My `JWTFilter` looks like:

```
package com.tsystems.covid.marketplace.backend.config.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthorizationFilter.class);

    private TokenProperties tokenProperties;

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(
        TokenProperties tokenProperties
    ) {
        this.tokenProperties = tokenProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Claims claims = this.getAuthorizationToken(request)
            .map(this::validateToken)
            .orElse(null);

        if (null != claims) {
            this.setUpAuthentication(claims);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    private Optional<String> getAuthorizationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Optional
            .ofNullable(request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER))
            .filter(header -> header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX))
            .map(header -> header.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param token
     * @return
     */
    private Claims validateToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(this.tokenProperties.getSecret())
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param claims
     */
    private void setUpAuthentication(Claims claims) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            claims.getSubject(),
            null,
            this.parseAuthorities((List<String>)claims.get(SecurityConstants.JWT_AUTHORITIES_CLAIM))
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param authorities
     * @return
     */
    private List<GrantedAuthority> parseAuthorities(List<String> authorities) {
        return authorities
            .stream()
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `hasAuthority` in stead of `hasRole`. `hasRole` will use the role prefix (which is `ROLE_`  by default) and checks if the user is granted `ROLE_VIEWER` which is doesn't. The `hasAuthority` doesn't use this so will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the default prefix of `spring`
try to make this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER')")
    public List<String> list() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

because spring add `ROLE_` before the role by default

Answer (score 1):

You give  `Granted Authorities: VIEWER` then u need to use `hasAuthority`.

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasAuthority('VIEWER')")
```

If you want to use `hasRole` then pass `Granted Authorities: ROLE_VIEWER` then u can use this:

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('VIEWER')")
```